# Using achartengine how to change center color of a donut chart

Tags: android, achartengine, donut-chart

I am using aChartEngineLibrary to make donut graph. It works perfectly, but I need to change the center color. Is this possible? I only could change the background, but I need the background and the center of the chart to have different colors.

Comment: The background color is the one providing the center color as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, this means that changing it is not possible unless I change the background color?